# Trying to upload file via PayPal API but get Bad Request error

Tags: node.js, paypal, fetch, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I trying to upload evidence file via PayPal API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/). I success to upload the file through cURL request:

```
curl -v -X POST \
  -F 'file=@mao.pdf' \
  -F 'input={"evidences":[{"evidence_type": "OTHER", "evidence_info": {"tracking_info": [{"carrier_name": "FEDEX", "tracking_number": "123456789"}]}, "notes": "Test"}]};type=application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-47363/provide-evidence
```

The cURL above works great!
But when I convert this cURL to regular fetch request I get 400 - Bad Request error:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append("file", fileBuffer, "@mao.pdf")
body.append("", "\\")
body.append("input", "{\"evidences\":[{\"evidence_type\": \"OTHER\", \"evidence_info\": {\"tracking_info\": [{\"carrier_name\": \"FEDEX\", \"tracking_number\": \"123456789\"}]}, \"notes\": \"Test\"}]};type=application/json")
body.append("", "\\")

fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-47363/provide-evidence", {
  body,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
.then(response => console.log(response));
```

Log of the form data:

```
FormData {
  _overheadLength: 457,
  _valueLength: 195,
  _valuesToMeasure: [],
  writable: false,
  readable: true,
  dataSize: 0,
  maxDataSize: 2097152,
  pauseStreams: true,
  _released: false,
  _streams: [
    '----------------------------315582696200967347353818\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="@mao.pdf"\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    <Buffer 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d>,
    [Function: bound ],
    '----------------------------315582696200967347353818\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    '\\',
    [Function: bound ],
    '----------------------------315582696200967347353818\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    '{"evidences":[{"evidence_type": "OTHER", "evidence_info": {"tracking_info": [{"carrier_name": "FEDEX", "tracking_number": "123456789"}]}, "notes": "Test"}]};type=application/json',
    [Function: bound ],
    '----------------------------315582696200967347353818\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    '\\',
    [Function: bound ]
  ],
  _currentStream: null,
  _insideLoop: false,
  _pendingNext: false,
  _boundary: '--------------------------315582696200967347353818'
}
```

Log of the PayPal response:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-44006/provide-evidence',
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

What's wrong with this request?

Answer (score 0):

Without a log of your actual request data and the actual error returned, it it's difficult for anyone to be of specific help, but the mostly likely problem is a failure to send the correct metadata for the file, or it not being in the proper order (evidence JSON object then file) as documented in the API reference.

For documentation and examples of how to properly format a multipart/request post with file metadata, see [RFC 2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387)

Comment: I edited the question and added the required logs. Can you take a look?

Comment: You should probably just log the output of what curl is doing so you can write code that will build a string that mimics that.